# Kendo editor doesn't work with html

Tags: html, formatting, kendo-editor

I have a Kendo Grid in my application

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TekstenViewModel.Tekst>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox'/>").Width(10).Hidden(!Model.Administrator);
        columns.Bound(product => product.Naam).Width(125).ClientTemplate("<div id='editorDiv'><div class='input'>#=Naam#</div><div class='editor'>" + 
            Html.WebCore().LinkButton(type: ButtonType.MeerActies, htmlAttributes: new { onclick = "openPopupDemo('#: Naam #', '#: ID #', 'Naam')" }));
        columns.Bound(product => product.Waarde).Width(125).ClientTemplate("<div id='editorDiv'><div class='input'>#=Waarde#</div><div class='editor'>" +
            Html.WebCore().LinkButton(type: ButtonType.MeerActies, htmlAttributes: new { onclick = "openPopupDemo('#: Waarde #', '#: ID #', 'Waarde')" }));
        columns.Bound(product => product.Opmerking).Width(250).ClientTemplate("<div id='editorDiv'><div class='input'>#=Opmerking#</div><div class='editor'>" + 
            Html.WebCore().LinkButton(type: ButtonType.MeerActies, htmlAttributes: new { onclick = "openPopupDemo('#: Opmerking #', '#: ID #', 'Opmerking')" }));
        columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<div id='deleteDiv'><div class='delete'><a class=\"delete iconBtn\" onclick=\"deleteResourceItem(#: ID #, '#: Naam #')\"></a></div></div>").Width(10).Hidden(!Model.Administrator);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .Events(events => events.Edit("onCellEdit"))
    .Groupable()
    .Navigatable()
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).DisplayDeleteConfirmation(false))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(true)
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(product => product.ID);
            model.Field(product => product.Naam).Editable(Model.Administrator);
            model.Field(product => product.Opmerking).Editable(Model.Administrator);
            model.Field(product => product.Waarde).Editable(!Model.ReadOnly);
            model.Field(product => product.RESOURCE_SET_ID).DefaultValue(Model.SetID);
            model.Field(product => product.Type).DefaultValue(Domain.Agromilieu2.Common.Objects.Entities.Resources.ResourceType.GLOBAL_RESOURCES);
            model.Field(product => product.Taal).DefaultValue(Domain.Agromilieu2.Common.Agromilieu2Constants.Resources.DEFAULT_TAAL_CODE);
        })
        .Create(create => create.Action(MVC.BeheerTeksten.ActionNames.ResourceItems_CreateUpdate, MVC.BeheerTeksten.Name))
        .Read(read => read.Action(MVC.BeheerTeksten.ActionNames.ResourceItems_Read, MVC.BeheerTeksten.Name, new { setID = Model.SetID }).Data("onReadAdditionalData"))
        .Update(update => update.Action(MVC.BeheerTeksten.ActionNames.ResourceItems_CreateUpdate, MVC.BeheerTeksten.Name))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action(MVC.BeheerTeksten.ActionNames.ResourceItems_Delete, MVC.BeheerTeksten.Name))
    )
)
```

Here's s pic of it.

[image]

When I click in a dotted button, it opens a `Kendo editor` with the value of the selected cell. So far, so god

[image]

If I do formatting to the text and save it, the next time I try to edit it, the editor won't open. Instead, the text will be edited in the default input.

[image]

Doing a simple formatting like

```
 <strong><em>Carolina</em></strong>
```

will still allow me to open the editor, but if I `underline` the text, for example,

```
<strong><em><span style="text-decoration:underline;">Carolina</span></em></strong>
```

the editor won't work and the text will be edited in the default input.

If I format the text with Heading `h1`, for example, after removing the underline, off course, the editor will work, but the text in the default input will have a scrollbar.

[image]

This only happens with formatted text. Any ideas??

Comment: In the meantime, I realized that I get a "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" error when trying to open formatted text in the editor